# Rails: rake db:structure:load times out on CircleCI 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, circleci, circleci-2.0

Currently, `rake db:schema:load` is run to setup the database on CircleCI. In migrating from using `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`, the command has been updated to: `rake db:structure:load`.

Unfortunately, it appears to hang and does not return:

```
$ bin/rake db:structure:load --trace
** Invoke db:structure:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:load
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional

 set_config 
------------

(1 row)

(END)rake aborted!
Interrupt:
<STACK TRACE>
bin/rake:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load
Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s)
```

[Found someone else with the same issue on CircleCI](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/rake-dbload-is-succeeding-then-timing-out/25944), no answers though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This seems to have something to do with the `psql` client's output to the terminal expecting user input:

```
 set_config 
------------

(1 row)

(END)   <--- like from a terminal pager
```

Not exactly a proper solution, but a workaround in `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
          - image: MY_APP_IMAGE
            environment:
              PAGER: cat # prevent psql commands using less
```

Comment: A similar approach addressed this issue for me with semaphoreci

Answer (score 4):

Ran into something similar recently on CircleCI with Postgres 11.14.

Here is the thread about it there: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/postgres-failing-with-upgrading-from-11-6-to-11-14/42932/2

Basically needed to add to the Ruby environment section in the Circle CI config.yml:
`PSQL_PAGER: ''`

Thanks to @swrobel for the fix.